# How to give a name to File{} for next steps whith "require" on Puppet?

Tags: puppet

Give an alias for a file seems to work. As example, the file which the name "tomcat_dir" could be used for next steps with " require => File["tomcat_dir"] " :

```
    file {"tomcat_dir":
            ensure  => directory,
            path    => "/usr/local/tomcat",
            mode    => "755",
            owner   => "tomcat",
            group   => "65534",
            recurse => true,
            require => [ Exec["tomcat_unzip"] ],
    }
```

But, if I do this :

```
    file { [ "/usr/local/tomcat", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir1", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir2", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir3", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir4"]:
            ensure  => directory,
            mode    => "755",
            owner   => "tomcat",
            group   => "65534",
            require => [ Exec["tomcat_untar"] ],
    }
```

How could I said Exec["test_unzip"] requires " file { [ "/usr/local/tomcat/dir1", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir2", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir3", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir4"] " without copy/paste all the paths?

```
    exec {"test_unzip":
            cwd     => "/usr/local/tomcat/dir1",
            command => "/usr/bin/unzip /tmp/${tomcat_zip_name}",
            unless  => "test -f /usr/local/jboss${version}/server/boursorama-${application}/version-${container_version}",
            require => [ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ],
    }
```

Because, if I modify some paths, I must modify in all "require" I use in my class!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making the `path` parameter the array of directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
file { [ "/usr/local/tomcat", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir1", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir2", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir3", "/usr/local/tomcat/dir4"]:
        ensure  => directory,
        mode    => "755",
        owner   => "tomcat",
        group   => "65534",
        require => Exec["tomcat_untar"],
        before  => Exec['test_unzip'],
}
```

So that you don't have to change `test_unzip`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to keep the same structure, you could declare the directory list as a variable, then both declare and require with that variable.

But, that sounds really messy - why not have the parent directory (`/usr/local/tomcat`) require the subdirectories (and define them en masse), then either have it `notify` the `exec`, or have the `exec` subscribe to (or require) the parent directory?

There's a lot of tools at your disposal in the language to create the process flow and dependency structure that you need, and brute force with a list may not be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

If a resource requires several other resources, you must declare that requirement.  There's no way around that.

In your case, though, I don't see why that `exec` you've specified requires any more than `/usr/local/tomcat/dir1`.